# asp.net web API post data via body form-data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, multipartform-data

I'm sending data to my web API using postman via body-> form-data

this is my code

```
public class get_CustomerSignIn
{       
        public string mobile { get; set; }   
        public string password { get; set; }
}
```

AND

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(get_CustomerSignIn Gsign)
{
string mobile = Gsign.mobile;
string password = Gsign.password;
        
.......etc
        
        
}
```

in this case I'm getting error my model objects are null, but while posting  using body->raw->json in postman its working

Simply my question is how can I get form-data into my model objects directly.?
(I cant change post type into to x-www-form-urlencoded )

Answer (score 1):

You can get form data value by using below code:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["Your key"];
```

Comment: but in this case we want to assign this value again to my class object, thank you for your reply, i found the solution, using API MULTIPART FORMDATA FORMATER package